# Need a postgres query which can pick latest version along with related next latest

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Status       Version  id
Unprocessed  6        abc
Processed    5        abc
Processed    4        abc
Processed    3        abc
Unprocessed  4        abc1
Processed    3        abc1
Processed    2        abc1
Processed    1        abc1
Unprocessed  2        abc2
Unprocessed  1        abc2
```

From this I want to pick Unprocessed data with the latest  processed version.
Say my output should be,

```
Unprocessed   6   abc
Processed     5   abc
Unprocessed   4   abc1
Processed     3   abc1
Unprocessed   2   abc2
Unprocessed   1   abc2
```

I tried using lag and lead of postgres but it populates the lag and lead for all the rows which I dont want. I cannot find a proper where clause for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT status,
       version,
       id
FROM   mytable
WHERE  status = 'Unprocessed'
UNION
SELECT status,
       version,
       id
FROM   (SELECT status,
               version,
               id,
               Row_number ()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY status, id
                   ORDER BY version DESC ) RN
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  status = 'Processed') A
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY version DESC
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=23c8b3a7d6dca94cfba913c04fe094c9)

Comment: Hi, the second part of the union would assign row number to all the PROCESSED records in the table. The prob is the table might have millions of processed rows.

Comment: Hi I doubt that happen. check fiddle